# How to relogin when session expires using apache Shiro?

Tags: java, servlets, shiro

I am building a java web app using servlets. For authenticating I am using Apache Shiro. What i need is a remember me feature. When session expires the login must happen automatically. I used the rememberMe feature in Shiro but nothing happened.Can someone help me please?

Comment: Hey @Nana, what have you tried, and what isn't working for you?
Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on asking better questions.
Let us know!

Comment: Well I have set rememberMe true using shiro token but I dont see any created cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Once the Session expires, your user will be forced to login again, by definition the authenticated session has ended.  Remember me will only remember the identity of a user, think of only shopping cart showing "Hello " and listing personalized shopping suggestions, but you need to login again before adding items to your cart.

This site has "remembered" you, but your the authenticated session has expired.

Comment: Okey I undestood it. Thanks Brian. Is there a way so I can achieve automatically relogin when session expires, using apache Shiro?